Расчёт физики космических объектов в 2D
Я совершеено сбит с толку. Почему в пресловутой Space Flight Simulator орбиты стабильны,замкнуты и подобны кругу, а мои орбиты напоминают ядро атома с электронами.
Возможно стоит использовать какой-то другой метод просчёта физики, который я не знаю, или у меня в рассчётах ошибки, я не уверен. Ниже мой код.
Сразу скажу, ошибки в конкретно отображении траектории нет, объект и правда движется чётко по траектории.


void Gravity()
{
    if (planet == null) return;

    Vector2 dirToPlanet = (planet.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
    float dist = dirToPlanet.magnitude;

    float gravityForce = gravitationalConstant * (shuttleMass * planetMass) / (dist * dist);

    Vector2 gravity = dirToPlanet * gravityForce;
    shuttleRB.AddForce(gravity * 0.1f);
}


Вообще-то в реальности круговая орбита — скорее исключение, чем правило... Так, редкий частный случай эллипса... Но вот такая вот прецессия, как на втором рисунке — действительно странно.

@Harry, да, я знаю. Тем не менее было бы интересно хотя бы понять, почему собственно в популярных симуляторах космоса орбиты всегда эллипсоидные, а в реальной симуляции выходит белиберда

А сама планета при этом движется? Мне кажется, как-раз ваша симуляция более приближённая к жизни )  У меня ощущение, что орбита сдвигается потому, что сдвигается сама планета, поэтому и сила, направленная к планете, меняет траекторию. Но это не точно.

Ну, либо, другой вариант - что симуляторы "вручную" считают траектории, не через пошаговую физику.

dist всегда равен единице, он вычисляется от нормализованного вектора.

Да, как раз про normalized хотел написать. Нужно dist брать от исходного вектора, а не нормализованного. Такая циклоида как раз получается из-за того, что притяжение не обратно пропорционально квадрату расстояния (расстояние у вас всегда равно 1)

@CrazyElf, движется планета или нет, не влияет на характер движения спутника. Если планета неподвижна, спутник движется по эллипсу в одном из фокусов которого планета. Если планета движется, спутник движется по эллипсу в одном из фокусов которого центр масс системы планета-спутник. То есть, это всегда эллипс для спутника.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Так то да, но фокус наверное в любом случае в центре масс. Мы не умеем отличать движется система инерциально или не движется, находясь внутри системы. Поэтому на самом деле относительно планеты движение должно быть одинаковым. Я в общем выше фигню там написал. Тут скорее соотношение весов влияет. Если вес спутника много меньше веса планеты, то центр масс будет где-то внутри планеты и сильной разницы не будет, если мы будем считать, что он совпадает с центром планеты. Вот когда веса планеты и спутника сопоставимы, там уже центр тяжести, наверное, важен.

@Egor, измените в 10 раз соотношение масс спутника с планетой и посмотрите что получится

Спасибо @StanislavVolodarskiy за ответ на вопрос, пусть, к сожалению, и комментарием:

dist всегда равен единице, он вычисляется от нормализованного вектора.

Правильным решением этой проблемы будет простое:
void Gravity()
{
    if (planet == null) return;

    // Убрать .normalized
    Vector2 dirToPlanet = (planet.transform.position - transform.position);

    float dist = dirToPlanet.magnitude;

    float gravityForce = gravitationalConstant * (shuttleMass * planetMass) / (dist * dist);
    
    // Перенести .normalized сюда
    Vector2 gravity = dirToPlanet.normalized * gravityForce; 

    shuttleRB.AddForce(gravity * 0.1f);
}



Добавьте еще скриншот, как в итоге рисует (это не обязательно, но интересно посмотреть)

@insolor боюсь, сейчас логика, в том числе отрисовки, слегка поменялась, но раз интересно

@Egor, круто. Так держать!

Хитрость в том, что при движении в гравитационном поле вектор силы меняется непрерывно, в зависимости от гравитационного потенциала, и если вы берёте значительные отрезки времени, то орбита тем сильнее отличается от эллипса, параболы или гиперболы - чем большей длины интервалы времени Вы используете. Простейшее решение - уменьшать интервалы времени между расчётными точками. Более сложное решение - получить точные формулы для расчёта движения по орбите, когда направление и модуль силы меняются непрерывно. Но тут надо решать дифференциальные уравнения.
Если считаете не в декартовой, а в полярной системе координат, то надо ещё вычислять и добавить в формулу фиктивную силу Кориолиса.

Вы хотите сказать что точности не хватает? И поэтому апоцентр смещается на одну седьму оборота? Я бы сказал, что это очень и очень странное совпадение.

Вот была у меня мысль и про дискретность. Сколько там тонкостей в этой "2 body problem".

@CrazyElf, поясните как ошибки интегрирования поворачивают эллипс ровно на одну седьмую? Как должны быть устроены такие ошибки?

@CrazyElf, там на картинке жёлтая и красная кривые наложены немного неточно. Вот это ошибка интегрирования. А цветик-семицветик - это ошибка в физике.

Когда-то я писал программу орбитального маневрирования вокруг Луны для калькулятора. Если интересно - программа здесь: https://arbinada.com/pmk/category/00838.html


Это и есть эллипсоидная орбита, а не белиберда. С планетами происходит тоже самое, что и с спутниками. Плутон вообще в перегее становится ближе к солнцу, чем Нептун! Апогей и перигей могут не так сильно отличаться, всё зависит от стартовых параметров. Если знать, как считать можно и окружность получить.

Vector2 dirToPlanet = (planet.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
// dist = 1, потому что normalized
float dist = dirToPlanet.magnitude;
// Vector2.magnitude - √(x²+y²)
// вычисление квадратных корней это операция занимающая много тактов процессора
// какой смысл вычислять квадратный корень dirToPlanet, если сразу же возводишь dist в корень?
// Vector2.sqrMagnitude - x²+y², то есть значение длины в квадрате
// п.с. что бы сравнить две длины, вычислять их корни тоже нет смысла
float gravityForce = gravitationalConstant * (shuttleMass * planetMass) / (dist * dist);


shuttleRB.AddForce(gravity * 0.1f);

А почему используется AddForce, а не присваивание свойства velocity? AddForce учитывает дельту времени симуляции и массу RidgidBody (+= force * FixedDeltaTime / mass). А откуда взяты shuttleMass и planetMass, если не из свойств тел?

Прочитайте вопрос ещё раз. ТС спросил почему у него смещается апоцентр орбиты. Прочитайте ваш ответ ещё раз. У вас по-прежнему dist всегда единичный.
